# Change PUG output directory

Tags: pug

I have a project where the structure is:

```
src/
--components/
---elements/
----style.sass
---pages/
----index.pug
```

The output directory is:

```
build/
--assets/
---css/
----style.css
index.html
```

If in the index.pug file I add the css

`style
      include assets/css/style.css`

It gives the error because it can't find this directory because it's only in the output directory.
Do I need to set something on the gulp so that it can get the file that was generated in the output directory?

Comment: any reason you're trying to avoid an external stylesheet? why not use `link(href='assets/css/style.css', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', media='screen')` instead?

Comment: I thought the include was the idea way of calling the style file in head

Comment: `include` inserts the content of one file into another: https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html

Comment: I understood, thanks!

I Created one variable path
```- const path = "../../assets/"```

and 
```link(rel="stylesheet", href=pathStyle + "style.css")```